# How to remove duplicate items from dict type dataframe using python pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have below data frame with duplicate data. I want to remove these duplicates from dataframe.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'test_id': [
        {'user_id':2, 'insert_date':'2020-12-23', 'is_admin': "true"},
        {'user_id':4, 'insert_date':'2020-12-23', 'is_admin': "true"},
        {'user_id':3, 'insert_date':'2020-12-21', 'is_admin': "false"},
        {'user_id':2, 'insert_date':'2020-12-23', 'is_admin': "true"}
    ], 'contact_id':[1,4,2,1]}
)

print(df)

                                             test_id  contact_id
0  {'user_id': 2, 'insert_date': '2020-12-23', 'i...           1
1  {'user_id': 4, 'insert_date': '2020-12-23', 'i...           4
2  {'user_id': 3, 'insert_date': '2020-12-21', 'i...           2
3  {'user_id': 2, 'insert_date': '2020-12-23', 'i...           1
```

I have tried below to remove dupicates

```
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['test_id', 'contact_id'], keep='first')
print(df)
```

But getting below error

> TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'

**Can anyone guide me how can I delete duplicate data based on 'test_id', 'contact_id' combination ?**

I want below output

```
                                             test_id  contact_id
0  {'user_id': 2, 'insert_date': '2020-12-23', 'i...           1
1  {'user_id': 4, 'insert_date': '2020-12-23', 'i...           4
2  {'user_id': 3, 'insert_date': '2020-12-21', 'i...           2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Series.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html) and filter in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) by original values, so original dictionaries are not changed:

You can convert dictianaries to DataFrame by [`json_normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html):

```
print(pd.json_normalize(df['test_id']))
   user_id insert_date is_admin
0        2  2020-12-23     true
1        4  2020-12-23     true
2        3  2020-12-21    false
3        2  2020-12-23     true

df = df[~pd.json_normalize(df['test_id']).assign(new = df['contact_id']).duplicated()]
print (df)
                                             test_id  contact_id
0  {'user_id': 2, 'insert_date': '2020-12-23', 'i...           1
1  {'user_id': 4, 'insert_date': '2020-12-23', 'i...           4
2  {'user_id': 3, 'insert_date': '2020-12-21', 'i...           2
```

If order is always same working if convert to strings:

```
df = df[~df[['test_id']].astype(str).assign(new = df['contact_id'].duplicated()]
print (df)
                                             test_id  contact_id
0  {'user_id': 2, 'insert_date': '2020-12-23', 'i...           1
1  {'user_id': 4, 'insert_date': '2020-12-23', 'i...           4
2  {'user_id': 3, 'insert_date': '2020-12-21', 'i...           2
```

Comment: Your answer is more accurate then  @SeaBean answer. so accepting and upvoting your answer

Comment: @SangramBadi - Thank you.

Comment: I am getting `type object 'Series' has no attribute '_get_dtypes'` error, while deploying in linux server using `modin.pandas`

Answer (score 2):

You can convert the values in column `test_id` to string first as follows before removing the duplicates:

```
df['test_id'] = df['test_id'].astype(str)
```

Then run your code:

```
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['test_id', 'contact_id'], keep='first')
print(df)
```

Output is same as what you desire:

```
                                             test_id  contact_id
0  {'user_id': 2, 'insert_date': '2020-12-23', 'i...           1
1  {'user_id': 4, 'insert_date': '2020-12-23', 'i...           4
2  {'user_id': 3, 'insert_date': '2020-12-21', 'i...           2
```

### Edit

You can restore the data type of column `test_id` from `str` back to `dict` by the following code:

```
df['test_id'] = df['test_id'].map(eval)
```

Alternatively, you can also consider the following code, which is generally considered a safer option than using `eval` (if the data is from external source) :

```
import ast

df["test_id"] = df["test_id"].map(ast.literal_eval)
```

See the post [Using python's eval() vs. ast.literal_eval()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15197673/using-pythons-eval-vs-ast-literal-eval) for more information.

After either piece of codes, you can perform your dict/json operations as usual like:

```
type(df.loc[2, 'test_id'])            gets: dict
df.loc[2, 'test_id']['insert_date']   gets: '2020-12-21'
df.loc[2, 'test_id']['user_id']       gets: 3

df['test_id'].to_list()               gets the list of dict instead of list of str:
    [{'user_id': 2, 'insert_date': '2020-12-23', 'is_admin': 'true'},
     {'user_id': 4, 'insert_date': '2020-12-23', 'is_admin': 'true'},
     {'user_id': 3, 'insert_date': '2020-12-21', 'is_admin': 'false'},
     {'user_id': 2, 'insert_date': '2020-12-23', 'is_admin': 'true'}]
```

Comment: You answer is correct, but converting to str will not use for other functionality. so @Jezrael answer is for accurate. so accepting his answer but I have upvoted your answer.

Comment: After converting to str, how can I convert it to JSON again for column test_id

Comment: @SangramBadi, try:  `import ast`  `df["test_id"] = df["test_id"].map(ast.literal_eval)`

Comment: @SangramBadi  A simpler way is just using: `df['test_id'] = df['test_id'].map(eval)`.  See my edit above.